# Configure the JDK in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have build in Jenkins, which uses the JDk 1.8. The JDK is of the type **"install automatically - install from java.sun.com"**.

I would like to configure the keystore (add a cert) for this JDK. 
Is it possible? Where is the JDK installed?

Answer (score 1):

If you have admin access go to Manage Jenkins > System Information
You should find some useful information there.

In addition:
jdk and jre are installed to /usr/lib/jvm/ directory, where  is the actual java installation folder

see [Linux jdk/jre setup](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ELB201/Installing+Java+Development+Kit+%28JDK%29+on+Linux)

Comment: Yes, thank you. But it's still a bit unclear as to where these "install automatically" jdk's are installed....